# Debugging in Java - Setting a debugMode flag

Tags: java, debugging, javafx

Apologies for a noobish question.

I am developing a JavaFX application.

I want to set a 'Global' boolean type variable 'DebugMode', Such that when a custom(I mean customized, or made by myself) exception is thrown, the getMessage() function can check the DebugMode variable to see if the DebugMode is set.

If DebugMode is 'true', then the exception can give detailed message for debugging, Or else just user friendly messages for the end users.

Is it possible in java, just like $GLOBAL variable in PHP? Or is there any alternative way for giving two different exception messages for developer and end user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go for -D argument (JVM Properties). This means, that when I start the application from command-line. I can do something like,

```
     java Hello -DdetailedDebugMode=true
```

And in the java code I can do something like:

```
  printError(Throwable t) {
      if(System.getProperties("detailedDebugMode") != null && "true".equalsIgnoreCase(System.getProperties("detailedDebugMode"))) {
          LOG.error("Here is the message", e);
      } else {
          LOG.error("Here is the message only");
      }
  }
```

Comment: To reduce the overhead this should be "cached" in a static variable on a central place.

Comment: Could you please explain @user714965

Comment: Place `public static boolean DEBUG_MODE = System.getProperties("detailedDebugMode") != null && "true".equalsIgnoreCase(System.getProperties("detailedDebugMode"));` somewhere to make this call only once. And then check against this variable instead of making this query maybe hundreds of times.